# getResources().getDrawable(rippleResourceId, null) return rippleDrawable with the wrong color

Tags: android, android-drawable, ripple, rippledrawable

I use android resourceId `android.R.attr.actionBarItemBackground` to set ripple.

On one item it works fine. On anther item I change the RippleDrawable radius, but then the ripple color changes to pink.

```
    int rippleResourceId = // android.R.attr.actionBarItemBackground from current context
    if (VERSION.SDK_INT >= VERSION_CODES.M) {
      RippleDrawable drawable =
          (RippleDrawable) getResources().getDrawable(rippleResourceId, null);
      drawable.setRadius(
          getContext()
              .getResources()
              .getDimensionPixelSize(R.dimen.ripple_radius));
 myFrameLayout.setBackground(drawable);
    } else {
       myFrameLayout.setBackgroundResource(discRippleResourceId);
    }
```

Anyhow had this problem?

Comment: are you using material design library?

Comment: setBackground and setBackgroundResource?

Comment: @PankajKumar what does it change? as I resolve the drawable explicitly and then set it instead of the id. no?

Comment: @EladBenda No actually both are same. I was suspecting but after looking into implementation, I realized you are correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

sending a null theme caused this difference

`getDrawable(rippleResourceId, null);`